# Regex to remove [] and all items in between

Tags: javascript, jquery

I can't figure out how to remove the `[ ]` from a string so something like:

`option = 'Texture[0]'` becomes `option = 'Texture'`

Here is what I tried, not sure why it's not working

`option = option.replace(new RegExp('/\[[^\]]*\]/'), '');`

Comment: without using regex you can use split. look at this [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/pt7nk9zw/)

Answer (score 2):

In a JS string literal, you have to escape backslashes. That is, to create a string containing a single backslash you would use the literal `'\\'`. If you want to represent the regex `\[` in a string you'd need `'\\['` (and so forth for each backslash in your particular regex).

Also, the `/` characters aren't part of the regular expression, in JS they indicate that you're using a regular expression literal. So if you're using a string with `new RegExp()` do *not* include the `/` at the beginning and end.

So:

```
option = option.replace(new RegExp('\\[[^\\]]*\\]'), '');
```

But rather than using `new RegExp()` with a string, it is simpler to just use a regex literal:

```
option = option.replace(/\[[^\]]*\]/, '');
```

If you have a longer string with multiple cases of `[...]`, something like `'Texture[0] Colour[3] Size[2]'` then you need a global replace, which you do by adding the `g` flag to the regex as follows:

```
option = option.replace(/\[[^\]]*\]/g, '');
```